# Issue with reading header variables with external credentials

Tags: externalcredentials, external

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZQLN.png)I have a scenario where I use external credentials to call an external rest API to get a connection-token successfully.

- The external system requires a browser-based auth provider to be implemented where after passing a client secret and key, it requires a human intervention to authorize the connection.
- Once the connection is established, a header variable must be passed to the API to get a valid connection token for further queries.
- I am using an external credential to make this happen where I have the header variable configured as a variable.

The issue is that the header variables are not at all passed on the second call failing the connection token. Have you guys encountered any issues with header variables passed using external credentials? I am sending screenshots of the configuration.
Buyan
[image]

Comment: I am unable to post any screenshots and would like to know how to do it for further clarrification.

Comment: Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful. If you're not able to post screenshots from your actual org, recommend that you sign up for a developer edition org and reproduce the config there, then post screenshots.

Comment: Try moving the header from External Cred to the Named Cred - see [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_cred_custom_headers.htm&type=5). If that doesn't work, you should open a support case.

Comment: Thanks @identigral for your answer. I will check with my team on this and see if this resolves the issue.